# How to load navigation properties on an IdentityUser with UserManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I've extended `IdentityUser` to include a navigation property for the user's address, however when getting the user with `UserManager.FindByEmailAsync`, the navigation property isn't populated. Does ASP.NET Identity Core have some way to populate navigation properties like Entity Framework's `Include()`, or do I have to do it manually?

I've set up the navigation property like this:

```
public class MyUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int? AddressId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(AddressId))]
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no built-in way and you need to do it "manually". At least I did not find one, when I had the same problem. Happy to be corrected if there actually is a way...

Comment: As a side note: `[ForeignKey(nameof(AddressId))]` is not required due to Convention over Configuration.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: It's not required, true. However, I always add the attribute just to be explicit. I don't like relying on convention "magic", and it also makes the code more obvious.

Comment: Likewise, particularly for people who may not be familiar with EF Core and its conventions.

Comment: Ack! Was banging my head against the wall for ages. Even in Core 3.1 this is still not working. The docs _seem_ to indicate this should work - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.0#add-all-navigation-properties - but it doesn't.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to either do it manually or create your own `IUserStore<IdentityUser>` where you load related data in the `FindByEmailAsync` method:

```
public class MyStore : IUserStore<IdentityUser>, // the rest of the interfaces
{
    // ... implement the dozens of methods
    public async Task<IdentityUser> FindByEmailAsync(string normalizedEmail, CancellationToken token)
    {
        return await context.Users
            .Include(x => x.Address)
            .SingleAsync(x => x.Email == normalizedEmail);
    }
}
```

Of course, implementing the entire store just for this isn't the best option.

You can also query the store directly, though:

```
UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager; // DI injected

var user = await userManager.Users
    .Include(x => x.Address)
    .SingleAsync(x => x.NormalizedEmail == email);
```

Comment: use SingleOrDefaultAsync instead of SingleAsync

Answer (score 22):

The short answer: you can't. However, there's options:

1. Explicitly load the relation later:

   ```
   await context.Entry(user).Reference(x => x.Address).LoadAsync();
   ```

   This will require issuing an additional query of course, but you can continue to pull the user via `UserManager`.
2. Just use the context. You don't *have* to use `UserManager`. It just makes some things a little simpler. You can always fallback to querying directly via the context:

   ```
   var user = context.Users.Include(x => x.Address).SingleOrDefaultAsync(x=> x.Id == User.Identity.GetUserId());
   ```

FWIW, you don't need `virtual` on your navigation property. That's for lazy-loading, which EF Core currently does not support. (Though, EF Core 2.1, currently in preview, will actually support lazy-loading.) Regardless, lazy-loading is a bad idea more often than not, so you should still stick to either eagerly or explicitly loading your relationships.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on lazy-loading. This project originated in EF6 so there are plenty of hangovers from there, in the codebase and in my head!

Answer (score 12):

Update for .NET 6.0 with EF Core 6.0:

You can now configure the property to be automatically included on every query.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyUser>().Navigation(e => e.Address).AutoInclude();
```

For more info check out:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#model-configuration-for-auto-including-navigations

Comment: Works fine, but beware of the cycles if you've one-many relationships.

Answer (score 5):

I found it useful to write an extension on the UserManager class.

```
public static async Task<MyUser> FindByUserAsync(
    this UserManager<MyUser> input,
    ClaimsPrincipal user )
{
    return await input.Users
        .Include(x => x.InverseNavigationTable)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.NormalizedUserName == user.Identity.Name.ToUpper());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best Option in my case is to add a package reference to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies and then in your services use the UseLazyLoadingProxies

```cs
.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(
    b => b.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
          .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString));
```

More infos
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I solved this issue by using the first option given by Camilo Terevinto but tweaked it a little and I inherited UserManager and overrode the GetUserAsync method to add in some logic I needed to load the property I needed:

```
public class UserService : UserManager<MyUser> {
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext context;

    public UserService(ApplicationDbContext context, IUserStore<MyUser> store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, IPasswordHasher<MyUser> passwordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<MyUser>> userValidators, IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<MyUser>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<MyUser>> logger) : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public override async Task<MyUser?> GetUserAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal) {
        var user = await base.GetUserAsync(principal);

        if (user is null)
            return user;

        await context.Entry(user).Reference(x => x.Address).LoadAsync();

        return user;
    }
}
```